# How to add lambda version in alarm name for cloudwatch alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a cloudwatch alarm similar to this form

```
  MyLambdaCodeDeployAlarm: 
Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm 
Properties:
  AlarmName:                  !Sub codedeploy-${AppName}-mylambda-errors
  AlarmDescription:           Alarm 
  ComparisonOperator:         GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
  Dimensions:
    - Name:                   FunctionName  
      Value:                  !Ref MyLambda
    - Name:                   Resource
      Value:                  !Sub ${MyLambdaLambda}:LiveTraffic 
    - Name:                   ExecutedVersion
      Value:                  !GetAtt MyLambda.Version.Version
```

I want to add the version name to my alarm name, I was thinking this would work but am not sure

```
AlarmName: !Sub codedeploy-${AppName}-mylambda-errors-${!GetAtt MyLambda.Version.Version}
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Should I be using !Ref? Or is there some other method?

Comment: Have you tried to run this template?

Answer (score 0):

It should be (don't need `!GetAtt`):

```
AlarmName: !Sub "codedeploy-${AppName}-mylambda-errors-${MyLambda.Version.Version}"
```